# "PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large" when run "tronbox test"

Tags: unit-testing, solidity, tron, tronbox

I am trying to run my unit tests with `tronbox test` command, but received this error:

```
Deploying contracts to development network...
ERROR: Request failed with status code 413
```

In the **Tron Quickstart** console:
[image]

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: i got the error too.  and i submit an issue in the project. https://github.com/tronprotocol/docker-tron-quickstart/issues/47